# Avoid multiple outputs of same record in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query that works with multiple conditions when selecting a record.

```
select
    uid, uid2, up, 
    datediff(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, tim) \"dt\", 
    id, behind, sid, spid 
from Z_uup, Z_snoop, Z_wshop 
where 
    (Z_wshop.sid='5555' or Z_snoop.id='5555' ) and 
    (
        Z_uup.uid=Z_snoop.id or 
        Z_uup.uid2=Z_snoop.id or 
        Z_uup.uid=Z_snoop.behind or 
        Z_uup.uid2=Z_snoop.behind or 
        Z_uup.pid=Z_wshop.spid
    )
order by Z_uup.tim desc;
```

The table `Z_uup` only has a single entry but it seems I get 15 repetitions of same as out put. why is this happening and how can I solve this.

Comment: What does your query try to do?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using DISTINCT?

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, ... FROM table1...
```

That way the repeat records will not be displayed.

If it makes slower, try with a group by with the field from Z_uup.

Answer (score 0):

Try with GROUP BY:

```
select  uid,uid2,up,datediff(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,tim) \"dt\",id,behind,sid,
spid from Z_uup,Z_snoop,Z_wshop where (Z_wshop.sid='5555' or Z_snoop.id='5555' ) 
and (Z_uup.uid=Z_snoop.id or Z_uup.uid2=Z_snoop.id or 
Z_uup.uid=Z_snoop.behind or Z_uup.uid2=Z_snoop.behind or Z_uup.pid=Z_wshop.spid)
group by uid order by Z_uup.tim
 desc;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Write `GROUP BY` in you query which your getting same record.